# Creating a seesaw in Unity 2D, should I rotate the Hinge Joint somehow?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Hi I have tried what appears to be every combination of angle limits, mass for a rigidbody, and various other available settings.

I have a pole and a board on that, when there is a collision on the board, the board should act on the hinge and seesaw to at most, around 35-40 degrees on either side. If you see the attached video, the board does about 360 before coming to an end.

Is it possible that the hinge should actually just be upside down? Is it possible to do that?

If not, here are my attached settings, maybe it's a misconfigured setting. Thank you in advance either way!

[image: Current Hinge Joint]

[image: Current Pole Settings]

[image: Current Board Settings]

[Video of current action](https://i.imgur.com/E9y1tcZ.mp4)

Answer (score 0):

In the 2D Hinge Joint settings, the maximum and minimum angle are set to 132.5° and 396.80°. You intended a much smaller range of motion, so the difference between the minimum and the maximum should be within the 70–80 range.

In the video, the seesaw seems to turn by approximately ¾ of a turn (270 degrees), and the current values, 396.80° - 132.5°, give us the total rotation angle of 264.30°. Close enough.

Try playing with these values.